# NSFetchRequestController use sectioning parameter as part of title for section

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a Core Data application with two entities. One is the `Order` Entity and the other is the `Sales Order Number`entity. The `Order` entity contains an attribute that basically represents which sales order number it is a part of. I am using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to try and group this list of orders by sales order number. This is done using the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter of the `init` method of `NSFetchedResultsController`. However, I want to use attributes of the `Sales Order Number` entity in the header of the section and this is proving annoying. I could get the first `Order` in the section and then backtrack from there using the relationship to get the `Sales Order Number` that it belongs to and then pull attributes from there, but is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Sorry if this is unclear.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `sectionNameKeyPath` and what attribute do you want to display as section header?

Comment: `sectionNameKeyPath` is SalesOrderNumber (the name of the relationship on `Order` and the attributes are all attributes from within `SalesOrderNumber`.

Comment: I just wonder that a *relationship* works as sectionNameKeyPath, shouldn't it be an *attribute* of the related entity? But anyway, I don't think there is a better way.

Comment: Technically, the relationship becomes an attribute, which is why it works. If you assign a one-to-many relationship, then the "many" objects on the other end get assigned an attribute that represents the object they are linked to via that relationship. That is what the `NSFetchedResultsController` is grouping by.

Comment: Yes, but how to you *sort* on a relationship attribute? - In `titleForHeaderInSection`, what does `[sectionInfo name]` point to?

Comment: I would presume it sorts on the object? Ill finish writing the latest revision of my code and find out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35002/discussion-between-pogo2065-and-martin-r)